# Разделение соподчинённых придаточных предложений запятыми при повторяющихся союзах

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, спп

> Так вот, фразу "я **обычно всегда** плачу за проезд" я бы
>   интерпретировал так: человек очень щепетильный, и он **всегда** платит
>   за проезд — но это верно только в нормальной ситуации: если же за ним
>   гонится банда с ножами, или он едет с острым приступом аппендицита,
>   или иной форс-мажор, он может и не заплатить (поэтому **обычно**).

Дело было так. Я убрал в ответе Sasha на свой вопрос (процитированном) запятую перед перед первым "или", сказав, что части придаточного не разделяют запятой, на что он вернул обратно запятую, аргументировав это тем, что "при повторяющихся сочинительных союзах запятая между соподчинёнными придаточными предложениями ставится". Потом я нашёл это у Розенталя с такой же формулировкой ([вот](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm), 109.3).

Похоже, он совершенно прав. Они соподчинённые, поскольку "если" можно отнести к двум оставшимся частям, верно? То есть можно повторить: "... или **если** он едет с приступом аппендицита, или **если случится** иной форс-мажор". *Хочу просто подтверждения его правоты, то есть того, что этот пример подпадает под правило Розенталя.*

Comment: Меня самого интересует, нужна ли здесь запятая: `человек очень щепетильный, и он всегда платит за проезд`? Походу, не нужна, но т.к. когда я писал этот ответ, я знал правила пунктуации гораздо хуже, то, похоже, в моём ответе ещё остались лишние запятые.

Comment: Артем, действительно, при повторяющихся союзах запятая ставится. Однако, чтобы точно ответить на ваш вопрос, надо видеть ваш пример. Не могли бы вы привести пример здесь?

Comment: Так в самом начале жёлтым выделено!

Comment: Саша, по-моему, это как раз очевидно: если "человек очень щепетильный" в смысле "как человек..." (в качестве), запятая не нужна, а если в смысле "человек (друг) является очень щепетильным человеком", — тогда нужна. Я понял в последнем смысле, чтобы обосновать, почему Вы поставили её. Только первый случай в любом случае какой-то неполноценный, допустИм как разговорный максимум и то без "и", я думаю.

Comment: В предложении ''человек очень щепетильный, и он всегда платит за проезд'' запятая ставится по правилу: В сложносочиненном предложении перед союзом и запятая ставится также в тех случаях, когда он присоединяет предложение, в котором подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, относящимся к подлежащему первой части сложносочиненного предложения или повторяющим его: ***Вдали по-прежнему машет крыльями мельница, и всё ещё она похожа на маленького человечка, размахивающего руками (Ч.);***

Comment: В вашем примере союз "и'' также также присоединяет предложение, в котором подлежащее выражено личным местоимением "он", которое повторяет подлежащее первого предложения - "человек".

Comment: Только я про "или" уточняю, а не про "и".

Comment: А обратите внимание на контекст `Так вот, фразу [...] я бы интерпретировал так: человек очень щепетильный и он всегда платит за проезд — но это верно только в нормальной ситуации [...]` -- походу `человек очень щепетильный` и `он всегда платит за проезд` здесь выступают в роли соподчинённых предложений (они по смыслу подчинены предложению, находящемуся до двоеточия) -- или я неправ?

Comment: Да, если рассматривать предложение "человек очень щепетильный и он всегда платит за проезд" как зависящее от общей, поясняемой ими, части сложного предложения (до двоеточия) запятая в этом случае не нужна. Но без этой части ( а при ответе я ее не учитывал)  запятая, конечно, нужна.

Answer (score -1):

В примере ***"....если же за ним гонится банда с ножами или он едет с острым приступом аппендицита или иной форс-мажор, он может и не заплатить (поэтому обычно)"*** нет повторяющихся союзов. Первый союз соединяет два придаточных предложения, второй - однородные определения: приступ аппендицита или иной форс-мажор. Ваш пример как раз подпадает под пункт  109.3.

Comment: Нет, `[действует] иной форс-мажор` -- это отдельное предложение. Если бы было так, как говорите Вы, то писалось бы `c приступом аппендицита или ин*ым* форс-мажор*ом*` или `c приступом аппендицита или *при* ин*ом* форс-мажор*е*`, а тут `иной форс-мажор` никак не согласовано с `он едет с острым приступом аппендицита`.

Comment: Согласен с Сашей.