# "..., что... и о...," — запятая в середине не нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Убрал запятую в Википедии во фразе:

*...услышав в очередной раз о том, что он (то есть Трошкин) сымпровизировал и о якобы совершённом им убийстве, те решаются на отчаянный ход...*

Запятая была перед "и о". Больше чем на 99 % уверен, что запятая не нужна, но всё-таки хочется, чтобы кто-то на все 100 сказал и привёл какое-то общее правило, включающее и этот случай.

Пока писал вопрос, вспомнил про свой другой [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420311/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7) про соподчинённые придаточные и прошёл по [ссылке](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm) оттуда, просмотрел немного; и мне показалось, что мой случай относится к §109, п. 3. Правильно я понял?

Спасибо! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Больше чем на 99 % уверен, что запятая не нужна, но всё-таки хочется, чтобы кто-то на все 100 сказал и привёл какое-то общее правило, включающее и этот случай.

Можете быть на все 100% уверены, ***что запятая нужна***.
Вы, видимо, неправильно грамматику фразы понимаете. 
Екатерина ответила уже, я только изложу подробно, поскольку такая ошибка, коли уж она встретилась, нуждается в последовательном разборе.

Ни о каких соподчиненных придаточных не может быть и речи, здесь всего одно придаточное, внутри главного.
Главное: 
*"Услышав в очередной раз о том ... и о якобы совершённом им убийстве, те решаются на отчаянный ход..."*

Придаточное (к слову "о том"):
*"что он (то есть Трошкин) сымпровизировал"*.

Да, в главном - однородные второстепенные члены *"о том"* и *"о совершенном убийстве"* (ну или "квазиоднородные", поскольку выражены разными частями речи). Но эта однородность никак не влияет на оформление придаточного.

> А как обосновать запятую после "убийства" тогда?

Вы этот текст правите?

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8

А то без контекста уже как-то неуютно, хотя он на самом деле ни на что не влияет.
Запятая после "убийстве" закрывает деепричастный оборот, начатый словами "услышав в очередной раз..."

@АртёмЛуговой, мой Вам совет. Прежде чем начинать разбираться с каждой запятой в отдельности, уясните структурную схему всего предложения в целом (в школе это называется "сделать разбор"). Убедитесь, что каждое слово, каждый член предложения должен найти в ней своей место. Тогда и вопросов, зачем та или иная запятая, будет несравнимо меньше. Правила-то вы знаете, только применить не можете.

Comment: Спасибо всем ответившим! Вот так я был почти уверен...) Пойду исправлять обратно. А как обосновать запятую после "убийства" тогда?

Comment: *Спасибо всем ответившим!* - А чего это Вы через меня это все передаёте? Мой ответ даже не понравился общественности, судя по всему )))

Comment: *А как обосновать запятую после "убийства" тогда?* - см. в тексте ответа.

Comment: Да, этот текст.) Правила знаю? Как раз нет, я совсем не знаю правил, как они строго звучат, только примерно представляю их сущность во многих случаях, и я совершенно не владею терминологией. В данном случае если б я подумал, то понял бы, конечно, что тут закрывается деепричастный оборот, просто не подумал хорошенько, простите.

Comment: *А чего это Вы через меня это все передаёте?* Надо же было кого-то выбрать, если не хотелось писать каждому в отдельности. ;))

Answer (score 4):

*...услышав в очередной раз о том, что он (то есть Трошкин) сымпровизировал, и о якобы совершённом им убийстве, те решаются на отчаянный ход...*

***Запятая нужна, так как она завершает придаточное предложение, относящееся только к первому звену однородных членов (о том).***

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна.

...услышав в очередной раз о том, **что он (то есть Трошкин) сымпровизировал**, и о якобы совершённом им убийстве, те решаются на отчаянный ход...

**Схема предложения**: услышав  (о чём?)  **о том** **и о** якобы совершённом им **убийстве**, те решаются на отчаянный ход...

Здесь в однородных отношениях находится местоименное слово "о том" и дополнение "о убийстве", союзная связь, одиночный союз И, запятая между ними не нужна. **Но двумя запятыми обособлено придаточное** "что он (то есть Трошкин) сымпровизировал".

**Примеры**

1) Запятая не ставится (придаточное предложение включено в однородный ряд):

Ему вдруг захотелось тепла и чтоб зима тоже была теплая. Приезжай через неделю или когда тебе захочется.

2) Здесь в однородный ряд включается местоименное слово, а придаточное обособляется. Знаки препинания ставятся по общим для однородных членов правилам (повторяющий  союз И).

Ромашов же краснел до настоящих слез от своего бессилия и растерянности, **и** от боли за оскорбленную Шурочку, **и оттого**, что ему сквозь оглушительные звуки кадрили не удавалось вставить ни одного слова (Купр.)