# "Подскажите, нужна ли запятая(,) и почему"

Tags: пунктуация

Читал тут один вопрос и попалась фраза: *Подскажите, нужна ли запятая и почему.*

Перед "и" не хватает запятой или всё правильно? Задавал уже [подобный вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424570/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0), но всё равно не понимаю, тут та же ситуация или нет.

Очень забавно то, что пример собственно и выражает мой же вопрос!)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужна запятая: два однородных придаточных, одиночный союз И. Второе придаточное неполное, состоит из одного вопросительного местоимения. Это же местоимение является союзным словом.

Comment: Спасибо, Sibylla!

Answer (score 1):

Запятая тут вполне уместна. Надо просто прочувствовать момент вопроса. После обращения "подскажите" по логике делается пауза, чтобы привлечь внимание. А это значит, что пауза на письме может быть обозначена именно запятой. Все  запятые рождены жизнью и реальной речевой практикой.

Comment: vvk, речь идёт о запятой не после "подскажите", а о запятой перед "и" (смотрите заголовок). В той-то запятой сомнений нету! Она не "может быть", а должна быть там.